# raster data expressed as percent

Tags: arcmap, raster, coordinate-system

I downloaded NDVI greeness data from the USGS Integrated Vegetation Mapping Viewer.  In the metadata it says that visual greenness values range from 0 to 100.  My data is from the period ending 3/5/12 in the NYC area my data table values only range from 0 to 68 which makes sense since it's winter.  I need to display the data in terms of percent, which seems easy enough, but has me hung up.  When I load the raster into the dataframe you can see that the values in the table of contents range from 105 to 255 (the BinValues).  I think I am having trouble understanding the actual data within the raster and how to manipulate it in order to obtain %.  The data is also in GCS (NAD83) and I will have to project it into Albers Equal Area to match my other datasets assigning the cell size to that of another dataset as well (30m) so I have to use a bilinear sampling.  I am a newbie at this so I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

[image: raster]